# How many transformation does elfman have

Tags: fairy-tail

Elfman Strauss, like his siblings, uses Take Over magic which allows all or a portion of his boby to transform into another form he knows well.  His specific type is Beast Soul which allows him to record and seal a monster's body part.

How many different forms can he turn into currently?  I suppose this would have to include separately how many arm only transformations we've seen and how many full body transformations we've seen.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, *most, if not all, information regarding anime character skills and abilities are found in their respective wikia pages*.

Anyway, from Elfman's [wikia page](https://fairytail.fandom.com/wiki/Elfman_Strauss#Magic_and_Abilities):

For Partial Take Over:

- Beast Arm: Reptile
- Beast Arm: Bear
- Beast Arm: Black Bull
- Beast Arm: Iron Bull
- Beast Arm: Stone Bull
- Beast Arm: Jet Black Sword

For Full-Body Take Over:

- Beast Soul
- Beast Soul: Weretiger
- Beast Soul: Lizardman
- Beast Soul: Belcusas
- Beast Soul: Ape
- Beast Soul: Sand Beast

Therefore, Elfman have **6 variants each of both partial and full-body take over**, which totals to **12 unique transformations in all**.